# Is there a simple way for parsing expressions in Python?

Tags: python

I'm solving this problem in codeWars `Simple parenthesis removal`.

here i need to find all the parenthesis and remove them. while removing, i also need to change the operation inside the parenthesis. (if there is (a+b)----> a-b
or ((a+b)-c)-----> (a-b-c)----> a+b+c )

i only coded the part where i can remove the parenthesis but can't think of a way for the conversion of operations.

```
def solve(s):
    s = '_'.join(str(s)).split('_')
    addr = []
    not_allowed = ['(',')']
    for i in s:
        if i not in not_allowed:
            addr.append(i)
    return ''.join(addr)

print(solve("u-(v-w-(x+y))-z"))

my output : u-v-w-x+y-z 
correct output: u-v+w+x+y-z
```

can i get help with this! i tried every thing i can think of but still can't come up with any thing. so a little help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of `s = '_'.join(str(s)).split('_')` ?

Comment: Why did you call your variable `addr`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the level of the inner groups (parenthesis), and only change the sign if the level is odd, when is even, It's a double change and the sign keeps unchanged, for instance:

```py
def solve(s):
    addr = []
    level = 0
    for i in s:
        if i == '(':
            level += 1            
        elif i == ')':
            level -= 1
        elif i == '+' and level % 2 != 0:
            addr.append('-')
        elif i == '-' and level % 2 != 0:
            addr.append('+')
        else:
            addr.append(i)

    return ''.join(addr)

print(solve('u-(v-w-(x+y))-z'))
```

It will return:

```
u-v+w+x+y-z
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Roberto's answer the most, but here's another possible approach.

You could also write a solution that, when it finds closing parenthesis, it reads backwards until it finds the matching opening parenthesis `(`, while swapping all the `+` and `-` inside of them. This is more similar to how expression parsing algorithms usually work.

```py
def solve(s):
    output = []
    for i in s:
        if i == ')':
            j = len(output) - 1
            while output[j] != '(':
                if output[j] == '+':
                    output[j] = '-'
                elif output[j] == '-':
                    output[j] = '+'
                j -= 1
            del output[j] # remove the opening parenthesis
        else:
            output.append(i)
    return ''.join(output)

print(solve("u-(v-w-(x+y))-z"))
```